Makefile Doesn't Recompile File After Source Changes
I am writing a small OS, but when I try to edit the stage1 bootloader source file it doesn't get recompiled.
Here is the main Makefile:
# Tools
ASM = nasm

# Directories
SRC_DIR = src
TARGET_DIR = build
TARGET = $(TARGET_DIR)/OS.img
OBJ_DIR = $(TARGET_DIR)/obj

.PHONY: all image bootloader run clean 

all: image

image: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET_DIR) bootloader
    
bootloader: stage1 stage2

stage1: $(TARGET_DIR)/bl_stage1.bin
$(TARGET_DIR)/bl_stage1.bin:
    @echo "Building bl_stage1.bin"
    $(MAKE) -C $(SRC_DIR)/bootloader/stage1 TARGET_DIR=$(abspath $(TARGET_DIR))

stage2: $(TARGET_DIR)/bl_stage2.bin
$(TARGET_DIR)/bl_stage2.bin:
    @echo "Building bl_stage2.bin"
    $(MAKE) -C $(SRC_DIR)/bootloader/stage2 TARGET_DIR=$(abspath $(TARGET_DIR))

$(TARGET_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

run: $(TARGET)
    qemu-system-i386 -fda $(TARGET)

clean: $(TARGET_DIR)
    rm -rf $(TARGET_DIR)

And here is the stage1 Makefile:
TARGET_DIR?=build/
ASM?=nasm

.PHONY: all

all: stage1

stage1: $(TARGET_DIR)/bl_stage1.bin

$(TARGET_DIR)/bl_stage1.bin: ./bootloader.asm
    $(ASM) ./bootloader.asm -f bin -o $(TARGET_DIR)/bl_stage1.bin

When I try to run the Makefile:
Building bl_stage2.bin
make -C src/bootloader/stage2 TARGET_DIR=/home/setorano/dev/CentralOS/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/setorano/dev/CentralOS/src/bootloader/stage2'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/setorano/dev/CentralOS/src/bootloader/stage2'

So Make doesn't even run stage1.

The line
$(TARGET_DIR)/bl_stage1.bin:

says that bl_stage1.bin has no dependencies, so it will never be rebuilt.
Instead you could replace that line and the line before by simply
stage1:

and make stage1 a phony target, that way it will always rerun the make command that goes into the stage1 directory.

Just to be clear: a target with no dependencies will be rebuilt, but only if the target does not exist.  If the target exists, it must be up to date since there are no prerequisites that could cause it to be out of date.  And, by "make stage1 a phony target" you mean, add .PHONY: stage1 to the makefile.
